# Erro ao clonar repositórios do GitLab

Tags: github, repository, gitlab

Estou tentando clonar um repositório que tenho criado no GitLab na minha máquina, porém o seguinte erro é retornado pra mim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usei o login do GitHub para logar no GitLab e criar o repositório lá. Quando tento fazer o CLONE, uso a autenticação de usuário do GitHub, porém esse erro é mostrado pra mim.

O que devo fazer

Comment: Já tentou clonar o repositório a partir da URL `git@gitlab.com:raphaelpradoo/DiabetesMonitor.git`?

Comment: O seguinte erro foi retornado pra mim clonando dessa maneira:
Cloning into 'C:\Projetos\DiabetesMonitor'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: E não aparece um "Permission denied" nessa mensagem, não? Se sim, falta configurar o acesso via chave pública, acredito eu.

Comment: Não. Apenas os erros que descrevi acima

Comment: Como comentou o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou aí em cima, o problema parece ser a falta da chave pública da tua máquina configurada no GitLab.

Comment: Onde configuro essa chave ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

No GitLab, eu defini uma senha para HTTPS. Ao clonar o repositório, foi só usar essa senha que autenticou.

Comment: Opa estou passando pelo mesmo problema, como você criou uma senha para o HTTPS ?